# In PhantomJS, does page.switchToFrame(k) require a delay before a call to page.evaluate() would recognize the new frame's document?

Tags: javascript, iframe, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS on a Mac OS X Yosemite.

The logic is simple:

1. Download some HTML page with frames.
2. Switch to each frame and find out whether it contains some HTML element.

Here's a snippet of code where I switch to each frame:

```
  for (var k = 0; k < page.framesCount; ++k) {
    page.switchToFrame(k);
    var eventHeaderFound = page.evaluate(function() {
      var eventArr = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr.twSimpleTableHeadRow th[scope='col']"), function(el) {
        if (typeof el == 'undefined') {
          return false;
        }
        return el.textContent.trim() == "Event"; }
      );
      return eventArr.length > 0;
    });
```

It appears the first line in the page.evaluate() function (where `eventArr` is calculated), often leads to this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.each(function(A,z){if(y.call(x,A,z)){w.push(A)}})')
  http://25livepub.collegenet.com/hash860B52FC5686DB189F1B18561705DAD0/scripts/prototype.js:2 in h

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():9
```

After inserting some logging directives (which, in the page context, do not write to process stdout), this error will sometimes go away.  Is it possible a delay after `page.switchToFrame` is required before the frame `document` variable is available in the `page.evaluate()` context?

Something like this must be happening.  At times, the logic works; other times not.  I've confirmed in the browser that the resource/URL is served promptly, so network latency is not an issue.

Comment: "undefined is not a constructor" comes up a lot. try adding line breaks to your eventArr-building code to get more specific error info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `page.switchToFrame()` is synchronous/immediate.

I suspect the issue is that you're trying to access non-existing frames. Calling `switchToFrame()` twice one after the other will switch to a child frame of a child frame of the main frame. You need switch back to the main/parent frame at the end of the iteration with `page.switchToParentFrame()`.

Comment: This helped.  Logic is now consistently working.  However, the same error still rears its head now and then.  I'll modify the original posting so you can see full body of error.